# How to import TypeScript Interface in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am exporting an interface from my `Types.ts` file in my project

`Types.ts`

```js
export interface Config {
    current: string
}
```

Here I am importing it, but am getting the error `Config' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Config'?`

`config.ts`

```js
const Config = require("../interfaces/Types")
const config: Config = {
        current: 'base'  
};
```

I am somewhat following the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), but I am running this in NodeJS so I am unable to use the `import` statement. What should I be changing?

Also, I have been able to utilize the interface previously by including them in the same file. This gives me no error
`config.ts`

```js
interface Config {
    current: string
}
const config: Config = {
        current: 'base'  
};
```

Comment: Once you figure out your TS project setup, you can use it like `import { Config } from "../interfaces/Types";`

Comment: Thanks @windowsill ! I used your method and I was finally able to import my interface

Answer (score 0):

Since the interface is not exported as default export, you should use

```
import { Config } from "../interfaces/Types";
```

You could also see this article

https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910